# AROSICS COREG_LOCAL saving an image using GDAL- TypeError: Dictionary must contain tuples of strings

Tags: python, dictionary, metadata, typeerror, gdal

I am trying to run the local coregistration module of the python package [AROSICS](https://gitext.gfz-potsdam.de/danschef/arosics).

As reference and target image I am using the data provided in the [tests directory of their repo](https://gitext.gfz-potsdam.de/danschef/arosics/tree/master/tests/data/testcase_inter1_S2A_S2A).

Here is the code I run using Python 3.6:

```
    from arosics import COREG_LOCAL

    im_reference = 'ref_S2A_20160608T153121_T33UUU_sub.tif'
    im_target    = 'tgt_S2A_20160529T153631_T33UUU_sub.tif'
    kwargs = {
        'grid_res'     : 200,
        'window_size'  : (64,64),
        'path_out'     : 'auto',
        'projectDir'   : 'my_project',
        'q'            : False,
        'CPUs'         : 1,
    }

    CRL = COREG_LOCAL(im_reference,im_target,**kwargs)
    CRL.correct_shifts() # causes the error
```

I keep getting the following error: "TypeError: Dictionary must contain tuples of strings" when AROSICS is trying to save the coregistered image using GDAL. The error appears in gdal.py in line [1467](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/d6c875e30d688c64be8ac0e206a899d9b21561f3/gdal/swig/python/osgeo/gdal.py#L1510):

```
    return _gdal.MajorObject_SetMetadata(self, *args)
```

The problem seems to be that the metadata variable global_meta is an empty dictionary.

Why is it empty? And how can I get Arosics or GDAL to save the coregistered image anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a stupid suggestion, but have you tried turning `'q': False` into a string (`'q' : 'False'`)